# How does one contact the moderators for matters not suitable for flags?

Tags: discussion, moderators

How does one contact the moderators for matters not suitable for flags?

(The dumb robots are telling me the question above does not meet "quality standards", so I'm adding this second paragraph to see whether that helps.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a question that someone might also later have, and it might be useful for the answers to appear as search results for later people, then posting here on meta is perfect.

If it is a question where you are pretty sure the answers will not be useful to anyone years later, then you would probably have the most luck by posting in the chat; currently (2022) the best chat room is here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13591/mathematics-educators .

You can also learn more about StackExchange's chat feature in general at https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq.

It's likely that there are other ways to communicate with moderators that I am unaware of; this is not intended to be the final authoritative answer.